# RStudio can't find my library on startup

Tags: r, rstudio

A couple weeks ago I asked this question on the [RStudio support forums](http://support.rstudio.org/help/discussions/problems/4367-rstudio-cant-find-my-library-on-startup), but it hasn't been addressed there, so I'm trying here.

I'm using RStudio 0.97.248 (current version) on Windows 7 and R 2.15.2.

When I open RStudio, after the normal R version info, I am presented with two errors:

```
Error in packageVersion("knitr") : package ‘knitr’ not found  Error in
packageVersion("Rcpp") : package ‘Rcpp’ not found
```

but I can load both packages without a problem using `require()`. (That is, after the errors on starting RStudion, I can enter `require(knitr)` and `knitr` will load successfully. The real problem is that I can't use, for example, the Knit HTML command on an R Markdown document, even after manually loading `knitr`. If I load `knitr` with `require(knitr)`, then open a new R Markdown document (for which RStudio defaults to a nice template), save it and attempt to Knit HTML, RStudio gives me a little error message at the top of the R Markdown document that

> R Markdown requires the knitr package (version 0.5 or higher)

I'm assuming RStudio isn't looking at the correct library paths.

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "\\\\gregorp.homedir.nebula.washington.edu/homes/R/win-library/2.15"
[2] "C:/Program Files/R/R-2.15.2/library"                               
[3] "C:/Program Files/RStudio/R/library"
```

with the first entry being where I can and do install packages (and my `Rcpp` and `knitr` installations are located). I think I'm having the same issue as [this guy](http://support.rstudio.org/help/discussions/problems/2837-knitr), but that discussion is incoherent.

I tried adding the line

```
.Library.site <- "\\\\gregorp.homedir.nebula.washington.edu/homes/R/win-library/2.15"
```

to my `Rprofile.site` file in my `R-2.15.2/etc/` folder, but the problem persists.

Comment: What you if you update the 2 packages?

Comment: What if you take RStudio out of the loop, and run R from the command line?

Comment: @Spacedman From the command line (or R GUI) `require(knitr)` or `require(Rcpp)` works just fine. Even in RStudion, explicitly entering those commands work just fine. However, if I try to `Knit HTML` an R Markdown document in RStudio, even after successfully manually loading `knitr` with `require(knitr)`, I receive an error that "R Markdown requires the knitr package". (Editing to add this info to the question.)

Comment: @agstudy My packages are up to date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I decided to start clean, I re-installed both R and RStudio and deleted my old library.

A risky option is running R (or RStudio) as an administrator---this allowed me to install into the default library, which avoids the problems of using a separate library.

In newer versions of RStudio I've had no problems using a separate library, specifying the site library in my Rprofile.site file.