# R cannot find packages after rstudio-server was terminated

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio-server

Has anyone run into this problem and know how to resolve it? I was using shiny in rstudio-server, and for some reason `runApp` was fetching a cached copy of the server.R file. So I terminated rstudio-server by doing `sudo rstudio-server restart` in my ubuntu 12.04 terminal. I also restarted my system. However, now I cannot find any packages! E.g.

```
> library(shiny)
Error in library(shiny) : there is no package called ‘shiny’
```

However, it seems like I still can do

```
> install.packages("shiny")
Installing package into ‘/home/alex/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1’
```

Comment: btw, I tried opening R from the terminal and it still can't find the packages

Comment: perhaps related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14201452/rstudio-cant-find-my-library-on-startup

Answer (score 0):

Before the crash, I believe `.libPaths()` was pointing to `"/home/alexfun/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0"`. After the crash, `.libPaths()` points to `"/home/alexfun/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1"`.

My solution was to copy over all the old packacges in the `3.0` folder into the `3.1` folder. So far that seems to work.