# Can't import a package using library() command - R Studio

Tags: r, ggplot2, package

I was trying to import the package "ggplot2", which I already downloaded, and can't do it through library(ggplot2) command.
It gives me the following error message:

```
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘Rcpp’

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: it's telling you that it is missing the package called `Rcpp`    run  `install.packages("Rcpp")`

Comment: or maybe even `install.packages("ggplot2", dependencies = TRUE)` to avoid the problem in the future.

Comment: Thank you all for your answer! I've tried both ways but still haven't got any progress...
Does the place where I installed the R folder affect the software's functioning? I've created a folder in my hard disk (C:/) but not in the "programme files" folder.

Comment: @Peixoto93 Can you load other libraries? For example, what happens when you do `install.packages("ggplot2", dependencies = TRUE)` followed by `library("Rcpp")`?

Comment: @dvanic I tried your way and still got this message after inserting `library("Rcpp")` command:
`Error in library("Rcpp") : there is no package called ‘Rcpp’`

Comment: @Peixoto93 See my suggestion below. Any luck?

Answer (score 0):

I would run,

```
install.packages("ggplot2", dependencies = TRUE)
```

This reinstall `ggplot2` and "install uninstalled packages which these packages depend" (from `?install.packages`).

Answer (score 0):

Try seeing where your libraries are being downloaded + installed to (not sure what the defaults are on Windows), and then see if R knows where to find them by using the `.libPaths()` command.

If not, add the directory where they are to your R environment as described in [this post] ([RStudio can't find my library on startup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14201452/3424793)) and see whether that helps.

`.Library.site <- "\\\\gregorp.homedir.nebula.washington.edu/homes/R/win-library/2.15"`

If it helps (but only if it does!) add it to your .Rprofile.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally managed to make gglopt2 work! I just downloaded "Rcpp" and then everything was fine (don't know why it didn't work last time...). Thank you all for your help! ;) Best wishes.